# Best performance solution for background image of 100 UIButtons

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uibutton

I have a UICollectionView with approximately 100 cells with a **rounded button** inside each cell. 5 cells per row, so I have to scroll down and up to select the buttons.

When the buttons are selected, the background image changes. I've done this in several ways which I expose below. Maybe it is not a very demanding view, but I was wondering what is the less expensive approach in terms of performance.

One solution I found is using an extension of `UIImage`  and setting the `button.layer.cornerRadius` like this:

```
extension UIImage {
  class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor?) -> UIImage! {
    let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if let color = color {
        color.setFill()
    }
    else {
        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
    }

    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image
}
```

and then, setting the button image background with:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.bounds.width - 8) / 2
button.clipsToBounds = true
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.greenColor()), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```

I've heard that setting the `layer.cornerRadius` is pretty expensive.

Another approach would be just designing an squared image, in Photoshop or similar, with a circle in the middle and letting the rest transparent and setting it as button background.

Or another option, that I still haven't tried, I think it could be making an 1 x 1 pixels image with a color and setting the filling of the background as tile(I still haven checked the code for this one). But I think this is pretty similar to the first way.

Would you solve this questions measuring the performance with any software or just knowing more deeply the Swift language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying mask to image. It's better because you do it once for each image. This should not affect scroll performance. Only what you need is mask image. It should be square image with white background and black circle in middle. [Here](http://jeroendeleeuw.com/post/33638733049/how-to-mask-images-with-core-graphics-in-ios) you can find example (obj-c). Swift:

```
extension UIImage {
    func maskedImage(mask: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        let maskImgRef = mask.CGImage
        let maskRef = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskImgRef), CGImageGetHeight(maskImgRef), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskImgRef), CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskImgRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskImgRef), CGImageGetDataProvider(maskImgRef), nil, false)
        if let maskedRef = CGImageCreateWithMask(self.CGImage, maskRef) {
            let maskedIm = UIImage(CGImage: maskedRef)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(maskedIm.size)
            maskedIm.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: maskedIm.size))
            let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            return img
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

**UPD**: code above is helpful if your images isn't monochrome. If they are monochrome you can use `UIButtons` with system type instead of `ImageViews`. Just disable `userInteraction`, set circled image for this buttons and manipulate `tintColor`.